# Add column and map IP to country - pandas dataframe with second table (lookup)

Tags: python, pandas

I have to tables. Table one has a column with IP number. Table two is a lookup with the IP boundaries for different countries. I want to add a column to the first table with the resp country.

table: ip_country

```
        lower_bound_ip_address  upper_bound_ip_address  country
0       16777216               16777471                 Australia
1       16777472               16777727                 China
2       16777728               16778239                 China
3       16778240               16779263                 Australia
4       16779264               16781311                 China
```

table two has a column ip_address and I want to add a column 'country' with the looked up value from table one

Here is what I tried.
This is not working.

```
#map ip to country
def ip_to_country(ip):
    country = ip_country.loc[(ip_country['lower_bound_ip_address'] <= ip) & (ip <= ip_country['upper_bound_ip_address']), 'country'].item()
    return country

X["country"] = X["ip_address"].apply(ip_to_country)
```

I do get the error:
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Please help.

Comment: Don't you want IP to be >= lower bound? This is probably causing it to return multiple possibilities.

Comment: I do have lower_bound <= IP & IP <= upper_bound
this seems to be right. It also works fine for a single look up.

Comment: Got it. makes sense now

Comment: Based on the value error though, it seems like there is a situation in which no result is returned. If you're going to use a function, it should probably return a default value if there is no ip within the bounds.

Comment: return country if country else None

--- did not solve it. is this what you meant?

Comment: I'm able to replicate your error if the dataframe returns results with multiple possibilities. Replace `.item()` with `.values[0]` and your code will work. However, the issue is that you could have multiple possibilities still.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your effort. Unfortunately, following your advice I do get another error:
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Would there maybe be another way to solve the problem in a better way?

Comment: This solution should work but it seems like you are likely comparing strings to ints. What are the datatypes of the ip columns from both dataframes?

Comment: `def ip_to_country(ip):
    country = ip_country.loc[(ip_country['lower_bound_ip_address'] <= ip) & (ip <= ip_country['upper_bound_ip_address']), 'country']
    try:
        return country.item()
    except ValueError:
        return "None"`
did work for a small subtable, but seems far to slow for the whole table.